# 1 & 1 laravel hosting problem [SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'XXX'@'XXX' (using > password: YES)]

Tags: laravel, hosting, web-hosting

There you go, I am trying to host my first site which uses the Laravel framework on 1 & 1, but I have some problems, when I try to connect to my site it returns the following error to me:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'XXX'@'XXX' (using
>   password: YES) (SQL: select * from XXX where XXX = XXX limit 1

In fact, I think that as soon as there is an exchange with the BDD it gets stuck :/

Can you help me ?

Comment: Have you changed DB credentials in the `.env` file?

Comment: I put "quotes'" for the username and password ;)

Comment: Your `username` will be root because this is the default name for phpmyadmin username and password should be empty if you haven't changed the default configurations of phpmyadmin change these and then restart your apache server.